# NaN comparison returns true?

Tags: javascript, nan

The last days I read how NaN always compares false even with itself and how to compare stuff when NaN may occur, and now I made a JS that compares two NaN true. WTF? Or did I compare 'NaN' strings?

http://www.bksys.at/bernhard/JS-NaN-compare-true.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>radioactivity calculator</title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="form1">
a: <input type="text" name="a"><br>
b: <input type="text" name="b"><br>
x: <input type="text" name="x"><br>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.form1.a.value=Math.sqrt(-1);
    document.form1.b.value=(1/0)/(1/0);
    document.form1.x.value=(document.form1.a.value==document.form1.b.value);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you compare strings as input values are strings.

Comment: As soon as you assign `NaN` as a value to a form element, you're implicitly converting it to string. So yes, you are comparing `"NaN" == "NaN"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed comparing the string `"NaN"` against another string `"NaN"`, which equates to true. The `value` held in text `input` elements is always pulled as a String type.

A simple way to resolve this is to prefix your values with the [Unary Plus (`+`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)) to convert them to integer values (you can drop those brackets, too):

```
document.form1.x.value = +document.form1.a.value == +document.form1.b.value;
```

---

#### Example

```js
document.form1.a.value = Math.sqrt(-1);
document.form1.b.value = (1/0) / (1/0);
document.form1.x.value = +document.form1.a.value == +document.form1.b.value;
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  a: <input  type="text" name="a" size="20" value="a"><br>
  b: <input  type="text" name="b" size="20" value="b"><br>
  x: <input  type="text" name="x" size="20" value="x"><br>
</form>
```

---

***Note:*** As RobG pointed out in his comment below it's important to note here that converting the string value `"NaN"` to an integer with the Unary Plus operator converts it directly to `NaN` because the string cannot be replicated as a numeric value. The same would happen if both of your `input` elements contained the value `"Foo"` - or even contained two completely different non-numeric string values. Whilst this solution does work, it may yield undesired results if you are to extend this code to handle non-numeric values as well.

Comment: That "works" by accident. In this case, the string "NaN" is no more significant than any other string that produces the *NaN* value when passed to *ToNumber*, e.g. `+'foo' == +'foo'` gives *false* since `+'foo'` evaluates to *NaN*.

Comment: @RobG that's a very good point which I neglected to mention in my answer. I'll add something in about that now!

Comment: Yeah, I put the brackets there to make sure the effect is not due to some unexpected operator precedence.

Comment: might I suggest that we use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` for converting strings to numbers instead of `+`? I know `+` works just fine, but it's not something I think ought to be taught to newbies.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JavaScript gotcha ;)

The proper way to compare NaN is to use the `isNaN` method.

```
var a = 'a' + 5; //NaN

if (isNaN(a)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: he's not trying to determine if a value is NaN, he's testing that the NaN comparison doesn't work as expected, and is thus probably quite aware of `isNaN`

Answer (score -1):

`NaN` is a special value in JavaScript. It doesn't even equal itself (also a quick way to test):

```
var a = parseInt('seven');
if (a == a) {
    alert("a == a"); 
} else {
    alert("a != a"); // This will happen
}
if (a == 'NaN') {
    // Won't happen
} else {
    alert("NaN is not equal to the string 'NaN'"); // Here
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u951v90o/

Comment: he clearly knows this, and is asking why his test of this didn't work.